# PGN-Extract output each game to a separate file with name like opponentA-opponentB.pgn

Tags: pgn

How can I use PGN-Extract to split a multi-game pgn into separate files with just one game per file.  With the pgn being named for the opponents?  Like opponentA-opponentB.pgn

Comment: Best to email Kent, the author. He's quite responsive.

Comment: As SmallChess says, as the author of pgn-extract, I am happy to field questions about the program via email and entertain ways to add additional features.

Comment: should be able to write some parser in python relatively quickly that splits file and saves each with separate name

Answer (score 1):

To a limited extent, you can do something like this already using the -Tp argument which selects games by a particular player. So:

pgn-extract -TpLeko --output Leko.pgn games.pgn

but there is not currently (2018.12.19) a way to have the file names generated automatically from the contents of the source file. Without a way to bound the number of players of interest this would require a lot of file opening and closing for a large input file. Some thought would also need to be given to how player names are mapped to file names.